# Where to put TypeBindConflicts in visual studio 2013 windows phone 8 project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting a error of reference confliction in a windows phone 8.0 project. I am using visual studio 2013 update 3. As I have done some studies about it and get this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64wh5743.aspx But can't figure out where to put that TypeBindConflicts. Please help me out. If there is another way please tell me. As I am beginner, whatever your solution is please write step by step. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Can you modify code that creates the conflict?

Comment: yes, i can modify codes. LukkhaCoder

Answer (score 0):

This compiler error, as described in MSDN, indicates that the compiler sees two types with the same namespace and typename from two different assemblies. This makes it difficult to the compiler to identify which type should be used when it is referenced in code.

If you own these assemblies that are producing the error, you can modify the namespace and/or typename to be unique to ensure the conflict no longer exists. If you do not own the assemblies but can remove a reference safely without impacting functionality, then that is another solution. If none of that works, then the guide from MSDN you provided originally describes some alternative approaches to help the compiler resolve the ambiguity.

The "TypeBindConflicts" from the code samples is just a "placeholder" name for the example - it maps to your type that has a conflicting namespace/name.

If that doesn't work for you or I misunderstood, it would help if you could provide some code or the specific error string.